# Best way to view server log files, and delete one?

Tags: logging, server, monitoring, remote-server, logfile

I have some basic logging set up for my web app. It will automatically generate a `log.log` file at the root of my project. Now I've deployed the app in Docker container on a Virtual Machine instance. What is the recommended way to view my log.log file and delete old log.log file? For example, I see a few options:

1. create a route like /log that returns the file when I visit the route (maybe add some basic authorization steps)
2. log into my remote server and view the log.log file
   Or is there any other best practices?

Comment: Do you use persistent storage? Otherwise once your container is stopped and the app not running anymore, all your files are gone with the container, including the log file. You can run, of course the app again from the image. If you want to see the log files while the container is running, you'll have to open a bash/bin to access the container and execute commands. If this is not what you mean, be more specific please

Comment: For this log.log file, I don't care to persist it outside the container. It's just meant to be an easy-going way to monitor how the app is doing. Finally I decided to return the file on a web request. But I'd like to learn if people use log file this way in real world situations.